# Sub setting shapefile to plot a region and addressing mismatch in ggplot & data

Tags: shapefile, r, ggplot2

I am plotting India's district map with data (cases).  First I read data for each district and district shapefile. Later I merge the two on district. Using fortify data I get ggplot. I get a beautiful plot using ggplot.

```
nr1 <- read.csv("../OUTPUT/working_districts_state.csv")
india.dist <- readShapeSpatial("./shapes2/2011_Dist.shp")
india.dist@data <- merge(india.dist@data,nr1[,c(1,3)],by="DISTRICT")
india.dist@data$id <- rownames(india.dist@data)
ss.fort <- fortify(india.dist)
ss.fort1 <- merge(ss.fort, india.dist@data, by="id")

d <- ggplot() + geom_polygon(data = ss.fort1, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group, fill=reg.cases)) +coord_equal()
```

I have two issues:

First, I want to plot a state separately. I sub-set the shapefile and try to plot using similar code. Problem arises when I use fortify command. The command creates an id column with ID extracted from original data i.e. india.dist and not the sub file. So when I merge state.fort with state@data, I do not get proper merge. I am still perplexed as I do not know how to reset ID.

```
kr <- india.dist[india.dist$ST_NM== "Kerala",]
state <- kr
state@data$id <- rownames(state@data)
state.fort <- fortify(state)
state.fort1 <- merge(state.fort, state@data, by="id")
unique(state.fort[,c(4:7)])
     hole piece  id group
1    FALSE     1   7   7.1
363  FALSE     1 173 173.1
719  FALSE     1 232 232.1
1384 FALSE     1 277 277.1
1960  TRUE     2 277 277.2
2013 FALSE     1 288 288.1
2561 FALSE     1 314 314.1
3018 FALSE     1 320 320.1
3349 FALSE     1 321 321.1
3753 FALSE     1 358 358.1
4144 FALSE     1 422 422.1
4735 FALSE     1 436 436.1
5204 FALSE     1 567 567.1
5663 FALSE     1 571 571.1
6292 FALSE     1 610 610.1

state@data
             DISTRICT  ST_NM ST_CEN_CD DT_CEN_CD censuscode reg.cases id
1           Alappuzha Kerala        32        11        598       259  1
2           Ernakulam Kerala        32         8        595       769  2
3              Idukki Kerala        32         9        596        42  3
4              Kannur Kerala        32         2        589        50  4
5           Kasaragod Kerala        32         1        588        38  5
6              Kollam Kerala        32        13        600       381  6
7            Kottayam Kerala        32        10        597        63  7
8           Kozhikode Kerala        32         4        591       237  8
9          Malappuram Kerala        32         5        592        95  9
10           Palakkad Kerala        32         6        593        31 10
11     Pathanamthitta Kerala        32        12        599        30 11
12 Thiruvananthapuram Kerala        32        14        601        97 12
13           Thrissur Kerala        32         7        594        99 13
14            Wayanad Kerala        32         3        590        39 14
```

Secondly, I suspect that the ggplot is not matching data (cases) to district properly. It is mismatching the data. I do not know how to check that such mismatch is not happening and if it is happening then how to fix it. I think this issue also involves handling ID in shapefile.